# Могут, или должны, ли разные сборки иметь одинаковый GUID?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assembly

Имеется старый проект VB.Net, который было решено реанимировать и переписать на C#. Для удобства было решено добавить новый проект в то-же самое решение (solution). Новый проект получил GUID при генерации проекта, который, естественно, отличается от используемого в старом решении. Проект не открыт для COM (`[assembly: ComVisible(false)]`) и не регистрируется в глобальном кэше сборок (GAC).

Должен ли GUID сборки соответствовать старому, если планируется полностью переписать приложение и в будущем использовать только его? Какие последствия могут возникнуть при использовании одинаковых GUID в разных сборках?

Comment: GUID сборки нужен для совместимости с COM. Для обычного использования и GAC, он ни как не используется, ну если только вы сами не читаете его через рефлексию для каких-то своих целей, такое иногда бывает нужно. Так что можете спокойно переписывать ваш проект не обращая внимания GUID.

Comment: @rdorn разместите как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUID сборки нужен для совместимости с COM. Кроме сборки, GUID, автоматически или с помощью атрибута [GuidAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute?view=netframework-4.8), присваивается классам, структурам, интерфейсам и перечислениям, также исключительно для совместимости с COM.

Для обычного использования, размещения сборки в GAC или импорта в базу данных на MS SQL Server он ни как не используется, ну если только вы сами не читаете его через рефлексию для каких-то своих целей, такое иногда бывает нужно. Так что можете спокойно переписывать ваш проект не обращая внимания GUID.